# MYSQL query to get 'n' rows nearby given row

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table by name 'videos', where one of the column is 'cat' (INT) and 'id' is the PRIMARY KEY.

So, if 'x' is the row number,and 'n' is the category id, I need to get **nearby** 15 rows

Case 1: There are many rows in the category before and after 'x'.. Just get 7 each rows before and after 'x'

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE cat=n AND id<x ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE cat=n AND id>x LIMIT 0,7
```

Case 2: If 'x' is in the beginning/end of the the table -> Print all (suppose 'y' rows) the rows before/after 'x' and later print 15-y rows after/before 'x'

Case 1 is not a problem but I am stuck with Case 2. Is there any generic method to get 'p' rows nearby a row 'x' ??

Comment: Would you not need the row x itself?

Comment: Could have sworn I saw almost the exact same question the other day, but can't find it now...

Comment: @cyberkiwi Row x is not compulsory.

Comment: The solution I posed does not make it mandatory. It shows `@n:=28` but if 28 doesn't exist it will `still` find the 15 closest to it (biased towards 8 before and 7 after instead of 7 before).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will always position N (exact id match) at the centre of the data, unless there are no more rows (in either direction), in which case rows will be added from the prior/next sections as required, while still preserving data from prior/next (as much as available).

```
set @n := 28;

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT v.*, 0 as prox  FROM videos v WHERE cat=1 AND id = @n)
    union all
    (SELECT v.*, @rn1:=@rn1+1 FROM (select @rn1:=0) x, videos v WHERE cat=1 AND id < @n ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15)
    union all
    (SELECT v.*, @rn2:=@rn2+1 FROM (select @rn2:=0) y, videos v WHERE cat=1 AND id > @n ORDER BY id LIMIT 15)
) z
ORDER BY prox
LIMIT 15
) w
order by id
```

For example, if you had 30 ids for cat=1, and you were looking at item #28, it will show items 16 through 30, #28 is the 3rd row from the bottom.

Some explanation:

`SELECT` **v.*, 0 as prox** `FROM` videos v `WHERE` cat=1 AND id = @n

- **v.*** means to select all columns in the table/alias v.  In this case, **v** is the alias for the table **videos**.
- **0 as prox** means to create a column named **prox**, and it will contain just the value **0**

The next query:
`SELECT` **v.*, @rn1:=@rn1+1** `FROM` **(select @rn1:=0) x**, videos v `WHERE` cat=1 AND id < @n `ORDER BY` id DESC `LIMIT` 15

- **v.*** - as above
- **@rn1:=@rn1+1** uses a variable to return a sequence number for each record in this subquery. It starts with 1 and for each record, following the `ORDER BY id DESC`, it will be numbered 2, then 3 etc.
- **(select @rn1:=0) x** This creates a subquery aliased as **x**, all it does is ensures the variable **@rn1** starts with the value 1 for the first row.

The end result is that the variable and **0 as prox** `ranks` each row based on how close it is to the value **@n**.  The clause `order by prox limit 15` takes the 15 that are closest to N.

Comment: Can you please explain what does "v.*,0 as prox" mean in the MySQL? {I am newbie in SQL  and don't understand the notation :(}